# How to convert string and/or array fields to act like a movie clip AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

My question is that how we can convert a string to to act like a movie clip 
OR
How to convert each field of an array to to act like a movie clip.

For example:

```
var days:Array = new Array("Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat");
```

and I want "Sun" to become a movie clip
Or

```
var str:String;
for (var i=0; i<days.length; i++)
{
    str = days[i];
    //and then I need to convert str to to act like a movie clip each time
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Your question does not compute.

Comment: You may as well be asking how to turn a chicken into a car. You can't. But you can *put* a chicken *in* a car. "Sun" is a string. It is literally an array of characters [S,u,n]. That is a very simple and basic element of computer languages. A MovieClip, on the other hand, is a very complex entity that has, as its most differentiating characteristic, frames that allow for animation, as well as x/y coordinates, width and height, visibility, rotation and a parent, just to name a few. A movie clip could be the parent of a textField, and that textField could contain a String. That's our closest bet

Comment: @Neal Davis please answer the question to solve the issue instead of reminding me the basic elements. The information given by you did not help me at all. If the way that I went through is wrong to get what I want, please tell me what is the right way of doing it!!!

Comment: @Neal Davis please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41086343/how-to-convert-different-line-of-a-dynamic-text-box-to-movie-clip-in-as3

Comment: it isn't a matter of me not helping you. It's a matter of you asking a question that makes sense. I don't grasp what you are asking because you are asking for something that makes no sense. Take a step back and describe exactly what you are trying to achieve. Turning a string into a movie clip makes no sense. Can't be done. Describe what you want to have happen for the user and we can come up with a way to do that which does not involve magic.

Comment: @Neal Davis please read the explanation in the link given

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130360/discussion-between-maziar-and-neal-davis).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is as Follows:

1. create a `movieclip` mc
2. create a 'TextField' text
3. make text be the child of mc
4. text.text = "Sun"

Then, you can use mc instead of "Sun"

Comment: can you please have a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41086343/how-to-convert-different-line-of-a-dynamic-text-box-to-movie-clip-in-as3 . i have tried to solve the problem with your suggestion, but when ever i click on the obj01 the last line will be getting bigger and not the current line.